# Thread on Images are not loading from bundle path While Loading the Webview?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my iOS app, I am loading the 'IYGLessonPlayer' html page in web view. Here, IYGLessonPlayer html Page load another html page i.e., index.html.

"index.html page will come as per the screen shot"

I have added a folder structure (created folder references option) in app bundle i.e.,

check the below url

https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9qjamfsg9gt867/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-02%20at%202.11.56%20PM.png?dl=0

My issue is:

I am unable to load the images, css  from the path in html page i.e.,

assets/images/background.png

assets/css/bootstrap.css

web view code

iOS code

```
NSURL *htmlFile =
[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IYGLessonPlayer" ofType:@"html"]
           isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:htmlFile];
[_contentWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Javscript code

for css

```
 $('.submitboxnew').css({
    "color": "#ffff00",
    "background": "url('../assets/images/background.png')",
    "animation": "none"
  });
```

for html loading

```
bundlePath  = [[NSBundle mainBundle]resourcePath];
rootPath    = IYG_G7_L03;
temp        = IYG_G7_L03_7.2_Pressures;
```

bundle path comes from native iOS

```
var path = bundlePath + '/' + rootPath + '/' + temp + '/';
var activity_path = path + 'index.html';
alert("activity path:"+activity_path);
$(".content").load(activity_path);
```

Please let us know how to load all the content.

Note: 
Here, from native code loading IYGLesson Player html page.
and from Javascript code loading another html pages.

Comment: Anyone have an idea for the above question,
Here am loading LessonPlayer html page. This html page loads another html pages i.e., index.html dynamically. In index.html pages is not loading javascript function